# Mathematical operations are not shown correctly in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: support, bug, android-app, mathjax

In the Stack Exchange Android app, mathematical operations are not shown correctly. They are shown in some coded words. To read the questions or answers with use of such operations, I have to open the question in the browser.

**Is this problem only with me or do the app need an update?** Here is a snapshot of someone's question in the app -

[image]

And here it is how it is shown in the browser -

[image]

Comment: Mathjax/latex expressions don't even render on iOS either (at least in comments).

Comment: @AndrewLi That means the both the applications need an update.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I couldn't find any such button any where, will you please tell me where its located, it will be very helpful to find that button.